# Using zyBooks and labs

Tags: java, labs, resource-information, textbook

Has anyone used zyBooks in their classes? I've seen some good comments on the SIGCSE list about them. I would primarily use this in our CS I class (Java) with their lab feature as a way to provide students with review and practice problems.

Currently, our CS I course only consists of 3 weekly 50-minute sessions, we have no assigned textbook (and much to my dismay, so separate lab sessions for students to practice the material - which in my opinion severely limits their uptake/comprehension of this material). I'm hoping this book/approach may be at least a partial remedy.

http://www.zybooks.com/catalog/programming-in-java/

It looks promising, but I would like some feedback from those who have used these (even if in other than Java courses)

--

To be a bit more specific (as suggested, +1), I'm curious about the students' reaction to the text and the labs. I.e., did they like the text, found the explanations clear, the lab/exercises helpful for learning and reviewing the material.

I'm also interested if the instructors found a greater understanding of the material by the students who used the labs.

Comment: This seems a bit broad. Would you mind specifying what kind of feedback you're looking for, or possibly which specific parts\aspects of the book you'd like feedback on?

Comment: I like this question now.  And welcome to [cseducators.se]!  I hope we hear more from you in the future.

Comment: I thought zyBooks Computer Organization and Design looked good, but it was too expensive for my students.

Comment: I think we should close this. its been around for a while and its about a specific brand of books which does not seem to be all that popular.

Comment: @Jay So we only should be asking about popular things? And the time limit you have decided on for questions is exactly how long?

Comment: @Jay I've chosen to keep this open. Popularity of the subject isn't a good reason to drop a question, rather it's a reason to keep it. This site might be the only place where uncommon resources can be investigated.